# Count on SQL Function return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, function

I am trying to count the number of records in my table that make a function I created return 1.  Here is what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isErrorMismatch
(@theType nvarchar(1), @theExCode nvarchar(2))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @theTypeAsInt int
    SET @theTypeAsInt = CAST(@theExCode AS INT)

    DECLARE @returnValue bit
    SET @returnValue = 0

    IF @theType = 'A'
        IF @theTypeAsInt >= 10 AND @theTypeAsInt <= 17 
            SET @returnValue = 0
        ELSE
            SET @returnValue = 1
    ELSE IF @theType = 'B'
        IF @theTypeAsInt >= 18 AND @theTypeAsInt <= 26 
            SET @returnValue = 0
        ELSE
            SET @returnValue = 1
    ELSE IF @theType = 'C'
        IF @theTypeAsInt >= 30 AND @theTypeAsInt <= 38 
            SET @returnValue = 0
        ELSE
            SET @returnValue = 1
    ELSE
            SET @returnValue = 1

    RETURN @returnValue
END

GO

SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1),LEFT([Exception Code/Category],2)) 
As MismatchCount
FROM dbo.[All Service Ticket Data 2012_final]
```

Every record that makes the function return 1, I want to count.  I am getting syntax errors in my FROM when I call the function.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thank you!

***UPDATE:

In order to get the count that make the function return 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(dbo.isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1), LEFT([Exception Code/Category],2))) As MismatchCount
FROM dbo.[All Service Ticket Data 2012_final]
WHERE dbo.isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1), LEFT([Exception Code/Category],2)) = 1
```

In order to get all of the records that make the function return 1:

```
SELECT Type, [Exception Code/Category], 
dbo.isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1),LEFT([Exception Code/Category] ,2)) as Mismatch
FROM dbo.[All Service Ticket Data 2012_final]
WHERE dbo.isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1),LEFT([Exception Code/Category] ,2)) = 1
```

Comment: Is there also a way to display the records that make the function return 1? Rather than display just the counts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalar UDF, which in this case accepted two parameters and returned a single value.
Some of the areas where you can use a scalar UDF:

- A column expression in a SELECT or GROUP BY
- A search condition for a JOIN in a FROM clause
- A search condition of a WHERE or HAVING clause

---

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(dbo.isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1), LEFT([Exception Code/Category],2)) AS int)) As MismatchCount
FROM dbo.[All Service Ticket Data 2012_final]
```

Comment: Hello!  thank you very much for posting! I am getting "The multi-part identifier "x.IsMatched" could not be bound."  Can you explain what x is?  Thank you!

Comment: @user1461332 column  "x.IsMatched" used in von v. answer, not my;)

Comment: Oops! Sorry! In any case, this helped!

Comment: @user1461332 that is right `SUM` will not work because the returned type of your function is bit. This answer while I like it will not give you the records you need though. You still need to go with my answer to `get the records` that gives `1` using your function. But glad we were able to help in any way.

Comment: @von v. In modified answer I convert bit into integer and then calculate sum. BTW +1 for good work!

Answer (score 2):

You are having an error because your function is not a table type or does not return a table and so you can NOT select from it. But nevertheless you can achieve it by doing this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)            
FROM    dbo.[All Service Ticket Data 2012_final] a
        INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT  isErrorMismatch(LEFT(Type, 1),LEFT([Exception Code/Category],2)) IsMatched, Your_PK_Column_or_Id
            FROM    dbo.[All Service Ticket Data 2012_final]
            ) x ON x.Your_PK_Column_or_Id = a.Your_PK_Column_or_Id
WHERE   x.IsMatched = 1
```

I just want to add that if the value you passed a value to `@theExCode` that cannot be cast to an `INT` then there will be an exception in your query.

Comment: Hello!  Thank you for posting!  I am trying to understand this, and had a couple of questions.  Do I have to replace the x with anything? Also, does the a represent each record from the table?  I am not sure what the x and the a mean..Thank you for helping!!

Comment: `x` and `a` are just alias and I used it because you have a long table name. The query won't show each record because you said you needed the count. But if you want to get `each record` then just replace the `COUNT(*)` with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the `CREATE FUNCTION` with `GO`. Also, your `SELECT` subquery needs a closing parenthesis at the end.

(Your question was about the syntax errors).

Comment: Yes, with fixing those I was able to select the records that were making the function return 1! Thank you!!!